# Quickbooks Online - Unable to Delete Attachment using Quickbooks-V3-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, laravel, quickbooks-online

Hello everyone I have unable to delete attachments. I keep having this error "Business Validation Error: The entity <null> does not currently support Attachable". I have tried a lot of code nut still on the same error.
Here's my last try:

```
$attachableObject  = $quickbooks->getDataService()->FindbyId('attachable',$f->qbo_attachable_id);
$resultingObj = $quickbooks->getDataService()->Delete($attachableObject);
```

This is the response from $attachableObject:

```
AttachableEx: null
AttachableRef: {EntityRef: "337", LineInfo: null, IncludeOnSend: "true", CustomField: null, AttachableRefEx: null}
Category: null
ContentType: "image/png"
CustomField: null
FileAccessUri: "/v3/company/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/download/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
FileName: "Screenshot(3)_3_14_61.png"
Id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Lat: null
Long: null
MetaData: {CreatedByRef: null, CreateTime: "2021-05-09T09:38:37-07:00", LastModifiedByRef: null, LastUpdatedTime: "2021-05-09T09:38:37-07:00", LastChangedInQB: null, …}
Note: null
PlaceName: null
Size: "157139"
SyncToken: "0"
Tag: null
TempDownloadUri:  "<<DELETED>>"
ThumbnailFileAccessUri: "<<DELETED>>"
ThumbnailTempDownloadUri:  "<<DELETED>>"
domain: null
sparse: null
status: null
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Actually the $attachableObject does not returns the correct entity. I change my query to:

```
$attachableObject = $quickbooks->getDataService()->Query("select Id from attachable where Id='". $attachment['qbo_attachable_id'] . "'");
$resultingObj = $quickbooks->getDataService()->Delete($attachableObject[0]);
```

and it works!